# Running a Linux VM (or WSL) inside Windows Sandbox

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v, hypervisor, windows-sandbox

I would like to run Windows Sandbox (that is based on Hyper-V) and inside there, I would like to run WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux, which runs on a Hyper-V VM) and other VMs (such as via VMware player). I believe that this might not work, but could anyone that's tried this let me know a) if I should not waste my time trying?, and b) is there possibly any work around for this? This is of course a question about nested virtualisation, but both Hyper-V and VMware are able to do that.

I tried to run VMware Player inside Windows Sandbox and it installs perfectly fine, but it would not let me create a VM. It does not necessarily follow that a VM should not be able to run inside a VM; I'm hoping that someone more versed in advanced VM knowledge on this could explain my options for getting a Linux VM running inside a Windows Sandbox please?

My test with VMware was as follows: I installed VMware Player 16 inside Sandbox. I used a `debian-netinstall.iso` to create a VM and got up to the VM being about to start, then received the errors "VMware player and Hyper-V are not compatible. Remove the Hyper-V role from the system before running VMware Player", then "Error while powering on. Transport (VMDB) error - 14: Pipe connection has been broken." On searching google for "vmware and hyper-v are now compatible", you will see that this issue was resolved more than 2 years ago:

> To fix this Hyper-V/Host VBS compatibility issue, VMware’s platform
> team re-architected VMware’s Hypervisor to use Microsoft’s WHP APIs.
> This means changing our VMM to run at user level instead of in
> privileged mode, as well modifying it to use the WHP APIs to manage
> the execution of a guest instead of using the underlying hardware
> directly.
>
> What does this mean to you?
>
> VMware Workstation/Player can now run when Hyper-V is enabled. You no
> longer have to choose between running VMware Workstation and Windows
> features like WSL, Device Guard and Credential Guard. When Hyper-V is
> enabled, ULM mode will automatically be used so you can run VMware
> Workstation normally. If you don’t use Hyper-V at all, VMware
> Workstation is smart enough to detect this and the VMM will be used.

Comment: It's trivial to modify Windows Sandbox configuration file to automatically any software you want. It's only a matter of then starting the VM.  You indicated it would not let you create a VM, but you provided, zero details on what trouble(s) you ran into.  I suspect the problem was simply nested virtualization, but without more details, I couldn't say the reason you had problems running VMWare within Windows Sandbox.  At the end of the day it's just Windows Containers.  Would need more information to determine if what you want is impossible.

Comment: I have updated the question to describe my testing and what happened. It would be very useful to me to be able to run nested VM's inside my Sandbox. Nested virtualisation is not in and of itself a *problem* (search for "vmware nested vms"). It can be slow, but is done, and that's my question: whether someone knows the advanced virtualisation trick/tweak to get this to work.

Comment: It’s likely the Windows Sandbox container is started without nested virtualization enabled. And even then, I believe VMware Workstation or VirtualBox could not work nested inside a container, that’s not what the compatibility is about. // IIRC you can somehow modify the Windows Sandbox base image. Depending on your actual requirements you might want to look into WSL 1, which has much-relaxed requirements.

Comment: Indeed, good idea, that could lead to a solution by modifying the base image, but yes, I wouldn't know what to change... I do modify the image regularly, but just in areas that I've learned. Maybe someone with advanced container / virtualization knowledge can see a simple way to unlock nested virtualization here. Here are two good primers on the base image modifications.
`https://www.systanddeploy.com/2021/08/how-to-customize-default-windows.html`  ,   `https://gist.github.com/Trenly/3e8ba9a9498c6cc12a9bb25e4179a98c`

Answer (score 1):

> if I should not waste my time trying?, and b) is there possibly any
> work around for this? [running a stable VM inside Windows Sandbox]

At this point, what you want will not work. It is not practical, did not work (I tried it on a Hyper-V machine), and is not supported (anywhere I looked).

I am not certain if VMware or VBOX would install in Sandbox.

But I am sure that Sandbox goes away on Host Shutdown, or Restart.  All hosts need to shut down from time to time.

This means you could easily lose work in your VM at an inopportune time.

Remember that Sandbox starts, ready to go (and goes away on shutdown). A Linux (or other guest) must be installed and (from time to time) updated.

So for these reasons, running a VM in Sandbox will not work, certainly not in any useful way.

I see a strategy or running a stable machine inside of a temporary machine as impratical.

**Footnote:**  I tried VMware Workstation V16 on Windows 11 Pro Sandbox and got configuration errors installing.

So I really do not see investing more time in a strategy overall that is not practical.

You may be able to run Sandbox from inside a VM guest (assuming a decent machine and lots of resources). So do it the other way around. It may depend on the virtualizing APP - VMware or Hyper-V

Comment: "At this point, what you want will not work". Thanks, but I think you mean you *don't know* if can work. I am unconcerned about losing work in the Sandbox (that is the point of the Sandbox). I use Sandbox constantly, so I know this; it is opportune and desired functionality. What you said on requirements for rebooting are incorrect. e.g. in my normal Host, I can run VM Player and I can install VM's. I do not need to reboot the host, and I can do useful work with VM's inside that host. Doing it the other way around is not useful for my needs, which is about VM's inside Sandbox.

Comment: VMware was re-engineered to operate in user-space and installs fine in Sandbox (see notes in question). You don't need to reboot to install it. If you know any of the basics of Windows Sandbox, you should be aware of the use of read-write `<MappedFolder>` tags inside the `.wsb` (no need to mention security as I am well aware of that) to maintain a VM from inside the Sandbox without any issues on Sandbox reboots (which I might not require). This question is for sure about nested virtualisation, but that is *not* a "will not work" situation. That's well used technology in fact.

Comment: My overall point was about the strategy of the issue. I have used both Sandbox and Hyper-V for some years and VMware Workstation fro some decades.  I think it is entirely impractical to run a stable machine inside a temporary machine.

Comment: I completely understood your point, You are saying that nobody can possibly have a use for this. I have specific and valid use cases for doing this, hence, I am asking a question in the hope that those with answers can answer. Essentially, your opinion is that it should not be done, but that's just an opinion. When you say "this will not work", that's an *opinion* and the opposite of an "answer". Your opinion is valid, all opinions are, and I'm happy to hear that, but it's not an answer, just a means to *derail the question* based upon your opinion.

Comment: Just to put this into perspective, twice over the last two months, I've asked questions on here and was told "no! that's not possible!". But I persisted with my questions and both of those times the people who were saying "that's impossible!" (as an *answer*!) were categorically proven wrong and I got a full answer. I think it's incumbent upon people answering questions on a forum that is about "answers" to ask themselves if they are *actually* providing an *answer*, or if they are just writing their opinion.

Comment: I have tried to do what you want and it has failed. Why ?  Not at all workable or practical. Not supported either.

Comment: It is practical, but it *might* not be workable, and that would be ok. What we know: a) we can install VMware Player without problems, and b) we know that nested virtualisation is not an issue in and of itself. Hence, it it is perfectly feasible. As another example, I was told flat-out that installing the Windows Store inside a Sandbox was impossible and was told that Microsoft crippled the Sandbox so that it cannot ever work in a Sandbox, but then I worked out how to reinstate full Windows Store support even though everyone told me "it's impossible". See what I mean?

Comment: See what I mean?   No, I do not see what you mean.  Sorry but no.

Comment: Of course you see. That's the problem with saying "that's not possible" in a forum about answers. If you think it's not possible, put your opinions in the comment under the question. It's not an "answer" if it doesn't provide an "answer"... But we'll get it working eventually John! Have faith! 

Comment: It does not work - Fact!   It is not supported - Fact!  . Yes it is not practical is a strong and substantial opinion based on 20 years of successful business consulting based on practical and workable solutions.

Comment: I've also got strong and substantial 25 years of successful business consulting in corporates (mostly investment banking), and I base everything on practical and workable solutions. It's definitely a practical solution (you don't know why I want it, so saying it's "impractical" is a non-sequitur). I think Sandbox is probably too constrained to do this, but thinking around constraints has always been very useful to me, so it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

Link to what I think is one of the best technical overviews of what happens in the sandbox, and what can be done to make your base in the sand... using a custom flare solution...

Like booting win11.iso in a windows sandbox, I doubt your objective is achievable (or desirable, given the dire performance and such) unless you persuade or emulate the Russonovichinator... maybe achievable circa ~GPT6, if there's still any carbon-based entities then, and an OS with windows sandbox.... but by then you'll probably have dockers in dockers in dockers on the nano AWS in your cerebrum, or something even quarkier

Great article

https://research.checkpoint.com/2021/playing-in-the-windows-sandbox/

*I just wanted winget to get wsl in my wsb so I could `git` `man` !*
Said no-one, ever, before, perhaps...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).